# Не переходит на другое activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть активити **Activityq** и приложение переходит в него из мэина. Я создавал активити через file -> new -> activity. В манифесте все правильно. Thats code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView name;
Button first;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    first = (Button) findViewById(R.id.first);

    first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activityq.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

Использую кнопку first чтобы менять активити
Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activityq"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activityq"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </activity>
```

Debugger показал что все должно работать на протяжении перехода(значения в интент верные). Где могут быть ошибки? В другом активити? Элемент кода из Activityq:

```
public class Activityq extends AppCompatActivity {

Question question;
TextView situation;
Button button1;
Button button2;
static boolean end;
static int true1;
static int true2;
DAOQuestion dao;
ArrayList<Question> arr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activityq);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    situation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.situation);

    dao  = new DAOQuestion(this);
    arr = dao.getAll();
    question = arr.get(arr.size() - 1);

    situation.setText(question.situation);
    button1.setText(question.button1);
    button2.setText(question.button2);
    true1 = question.true1;
    true2 = question.true2;
    end = question.end;
```

Comment: need full manifest.
and, english stack is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Go to https://stackoverflow.com guy, this is russian community.

Comment: можно было на русском?

Comment: нужно было на русском)

Comment: все теперь перевел

Comment: Закомментите весь код после `setContentView` во второй активити и проверьте..

Comment: А Вы точно кликаете на кнопку с id `first`? Просто ничего не происходит?

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку выкидывает из приложения или не происходит никаких действий?

Comment: После нажатия на кнопку все вылетает. После закомментирования кода во втором активити наконец-то заработало. Теперь я понял где искать ошибку.

Comment: LOGCAT!!! Почему нельзя сначала посмотреть в логе почему всё упало, попытаться разобраться. Почему надо просто писать сюда из-за каждой проблемки?